# What's wrong with this cat's mouth?

Tags: cats, diseases, dental-care

This is a street cat I have come across. Its two lower canines seem like protruding outward, instead of pointing upward as they normally do here they point almost horizontally. Its mouth is always slightly open. What's going on?

[Video](https://youtu.be/GxuAeb0nHqI)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You write "This is a street cat I have come across." but this cat has a collar and might not be feral or a "street cat". In case you decide to do anything with it (like bring it to a vet or adopt it) I strongly advice you to try and find it's current owner first.

Answer (score 4):

I think the cat might have a broken lower jaw,This can sometimes happen after a long fall and is not uncommon in cats that have had this type of accidents.

It might be a birth defect but this is less likely as it had been a problem getting milk from the kittens mother.

The street cat look a bit underweight so if it is possible for you try to feed it canned food.

If it is possible for you try to get the cat to a vet,The treatment of this type of injury will be expensive but it is possible to get it treated if you have the resources to do so.